# Prove that the integral of a product of two functions if finite

Tags: real-analysis

A have two functions $g(\mathbf{x})$ and $f(\mathbf{x})$, where $\mathbf{x}$ is a d-dimensional vector that belong to the $d-1$-dimensional simplex $S$.
If I know that 
$$
\int_{\mathcal{S}}  g(\mathbf{x}) d \mathbf{x}< \infty,
$$ 
$$
\int_{\mathcal{S}}  f(\mathbf{x}) d \mathbf{x}< \infty
$$
 and  for any  $\mathbf{x}$ I have that $g(\mathbf{x})>0$ and $f(\mathbf{x})>0$.

Can I say that the 
$$
\int_{\mathcal{S}}  g(\mathbf{x})f(\mathbf{x}) d \mathbf{x}< \infty? (1)
$$ 
How can I prove it? which are the conditions that makes (1) true?

EDIT:
I added the domain of $\mathbf{x}$ and the integration.

Comment: You can't say that. It depends on what is the domain of integration.

Comment: You cannot say that. And that you cannot does not really depend on the domain of integration.

Comment: @rldias I added the domain

Comment: Continuity of $f$ and $g$ is sufficient, since a simplex is compact. In general, it's hard to say whether $fg$ is integrable.

Comment: A weaker (but still sufficient) condition is that $f\in L^p(S)$ and $g\in L^q(S)$ for $1/p+1/q=1$, since is this case $fg\in L^1(S)$ (Hölder's inequality).